# jQuery UI - after dragging the item is not draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have problem with dragging between columns. The first drag works OK, but when I want to move to the other cell, It does not work (I can only sort).

When I remove

```
helper: "clone"
```

everything works OK, but table is messy (cells "jumping") while I dragging item.

Thanks for the help.

http://jsfiddle.net/81jg164n/

Comment: It looks like the items are still draggable but only within the current `<ul>`. Is it your intention to be able to move them to other `<ul>` elements?

Comment: Yes. I solved It (http://jsfiddle.net/j8tz5ej3/). But there is problem, that i can move with item over the column with time. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Although the author seems to have found his own answer, I thought that I would add what helped me.

My own draggable element was no longer drag after the first movement.

I had `return false` at the end of my `drag` function - by removing the `return false` line, my draggable element can now be dragged more than once.